# Unity Facebook plugin FacebookContentProvider not found runtime exception

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I add facebook plugin to my project, following all the steps.
It is working fine in unity editor. But when I tried exporting a build and tested on android device it is not working anymore.
The app crash on the initial launch itself.It closes immediately.

I tried connecting the app to the adb logcat and found some errors on the log, which is follows.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn’t find class “com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider” on path: DexPathList[[zip file “/data/app/com.studio.halfo-1/base.apk”],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.studio.halfo-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.studio.halfo-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5175)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4767)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn’t find class “com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider” on path: DexPathList[[zip file “/data/app/com.studio.halfo-1/base.apk”],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.studio.halfo-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.studio.halfo-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5160)
… 10 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

If i tried commenting the FacebookContentProvider in the AndroidManifest.xml file then the app fails on the facebook initialisation. It throws Facebook is not initialised error.

Anyone Please let me know what i am missing on this. 
My Unity Version is  2018.4.3f1.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually run the play services resolver

run "/Assets/Play Service Resolver/Android Resolver/Delete Resolved Libraries"

run "/Assets/Play Service Resolver/Android Resolver/Resolve"

Then all of the correct aar files will get downloaded.

This worked for me. On PC the play services resolver didn’t automatically run. Had to do it manually